# Turning Scala Actors To Akka Actors: One Instance To Call Methods On

Tags: scala, actor, akka

Recently I was switching from scala actors to akka actors, but noticed that akka actors use `ActorRef` instead of the instance object:

```
val actorRef: ActorRef = Actor.actorOf(new MyActor)
```

So I tried:

```
val myActor = new MyActor
val actorRef: ActorRef = Actor.actorOf(x)
```

... to have both: 1) `ActorRef` to send messages and 2) `MyActor` to call methods on.
But I got:

```
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: ActorRef for instance of actor [MyActor] is not in scope.
```

So my question is: How can I obtain an instance (of some type) on which I can call `ActorRef`-like methods like `!` AND also methods from the `MyActor` instance?

Comment: Why are you calling methods on the actor? What sort of methods? I would think that calling methods directly on the actor is dangerous, and you should think about changing how this works.

Comment: @Submonoid I know thats dangerous. It´s some kind of convenience method, as you can see in my example it does not change the actors internal state (the dangerous part) but only sends a message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're doing is a **terrible** idea.  So just stop right now, step away from the keyboard, and go to [the Akka Documentation](http://akka.io/docs) and read up on Actors.

Consider this:

```
class YourActor extends Actor {
  var mutableStuff = ...
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      // mess with mutableStuff
  }
  def publicMethod = // mess with mutableStuff
}
```

Now, set up your system and start sending messages and calling that method from other threads. Boom!

You're doing **precisely** what Akka and the Actor model help you prevent.  You're actually bending over backwards to break what they've already fixed :)  They won't let you do it.

Now, you can unit test by accessing methods directly but you need a TestActorRef for that.  While you're reading the docs, read through the section on Testing.

Comment: Thanks to make things clear. I suppose that was the reason why 'ActorRef' even exists (beside other facts, e.g. its serializable to send across network). I don´t want to change the mutable part of the actor, which is dangerous (when it´s called from another thread), I know. As mentioned this are only convenience methods. But your´re right I should take another approach instead of breaking the Actor Model.

Comment: I get that, but that's not the way.  Akka isn't just a toolkit, it's a paradigm for concurrent, fault tolerant programming.  What you're building is really just a house of cards.  It would be "convenient" until some joker somewhere, not knowing any better, mutated state.  All you've done is put an unlocked door on hell with a sign on it saying, "Please don't open".

Comment: Nice analogy. I fear I am that joker respectively my future self :D

Comment: Perhaps the akka guys will find a way to even prevent my way of hacking this.

Comment: They've done a pretty good job IMO. There will always be a way... they can't stop an Actor from mutating global state, for example.  That's why you have to swallow the _paradigm_.  Don't just use the toolkit, grasp the paradigm and code to it and you'll be good.

Comment: Not only that. But the way fault-tolerance is done in Akka, the Actor _instance_ will be replaced on failure, so you'll hang onto a broken reference. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The best that I can up with is the following, quite dirty:
Is there a better way?

```
import akka.actor._

trait ActorCom {
  var actorRefForInitialization: ActorRef = _
  lazy val actorRef: ActorRef = actorRefForInitialization
  def ?(message: Any)(implicit channel: UntypedChannel = NullChannel, timeout: Actor.Timeout = Actor.defaultTimeout) = actorRef ? message
  def !(msg: Any)(implicit sender: UntypedChannel) = actorRef ! msg
  def start = actorRef.start
}

object AkkaActorFactory {
  def apply[A <: Actor](newInstance: => A with ActorCom): A with ActorCom = {
    var instance: Option[A with ActorCom] = None
    val actorRef = Actor.actorOf({
      instance = Some(newInstance)
      instance.get
    })
    instance.get.actorRefForInitialization = actorRef
    instance.get.actorRef // touch lazy val in ActorCom, to make it equal to actorRef and then its fixed (immutable)
    instance.get
  }
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "test1" => println("good")
    case "test2" => println("fine")
    case _       => println("bad")
  }
  def sendTestMsg2Myself = self ! "test2"
}

val myActor = AkkaActorFactory(newInstance = new MyActor with ActorCom)
myActor.start
myActor ! "test1"
myActor.sendTestMsg2Myself // example for calling methods on MyActor-instance
myActor ! PoisonPill
```